# clk prescaler with possible glitches

Tags: fpga

I‘m new here and have the following problem. I have developed a module in vhdl which scales the frequency of an input clk by the input prescaling value (0-255) s.t. the frequency of the output signal is f_out=f_in/(1+prescale).

My design works fine in simulation but from past uni courses and eyperience I know this is still far from working in hardware.

What I believe might cause a problem is the following: I have an internal signal that switches level when a rising edge for clk_out should occur and one which switches level when a falling edge for clk_out should occur. clk_out is then simply an XOR of both...so behind these two buffered internal signals I have a small combinatorial part that generates clk_out. My design keeps the duty cycle at 50% so a falling edge can be generated at a falling edge of clk_in, thus I cant simply flop clk_out.

So my questions are:

- Will the combinatorial part cause problems in an fpga design? Afterall...clk_out will be used as a cloxk signal.
- Is there perhaps a better way to approach this? I really only need the rising edge of clk_out so the duty cycle is not too crutial, however how will.I realize the clk_in=clk_out case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(From a Xilinx experience)

- You can place a timing constraint to ensure that the propagation time of the combinatorial parts (around the XOR) are kept shorter than the clock high and low states. Ideally, they should be balanced.
- Clock buffers are automatically inferred when a commbinatorial signal is used as a clock input. You can check that by reading the synthesis report.
- Some FPGA families have special glitch avoidance clock multiplexers, which could be used to select between the 'direct clock' and the 'clock division' paths : "BUFGMUX"
- You can use a clock multiplier PLL to generate a 2X clock and achieve 50% duty cycle whatever the input clock shape is.

If you only need low frequencies (maybe up to 50...100MHz, depends on FPGA family), the combinatorial XOR should work. If you need high frequencies, a PLL, and/or clock multiplexers should be better.

Comment: Thanks! That definitely helped. Regarding the individual points you posted:

- With balanced, do you mean a duty cycle of 50% should be preferred?

- Your second and third points are clear to me :)

- So generate a clk with f_clk = 2*f_in s.t. the falling edge of my original clk_out will always be on a rising edge of the new clk generated via PLL? Do FPGAs typically have PLL modules? I assume a digital PLL is not sufficient, so its not something I could implement.

My target frequencies are below 50MHz so I think I'll go with the constraints method.

Comment: For (1), it is rather than propagation times should be similar, something which cannot really be guaranteed without manually constraining each gate location, and checking with a oscilloscope the actual waveform. For (4) PLL/DLL clock multipliers or even synthetisers are now quite commonplace, they are practically necessary for handling fast interfaces like LVDS, dynamic RAM, or having fast clocks without using difficult to interface high frequency quartz oscillators.